# Generating Patterns Using For Loops

Tags: java, loops

How would I generate this sequence using only `for` loops?

```
***+++------+++***
```

I tried doing it like this but it doesn't look right

```
String u ="";
for(i=1;i<3;++i)
{
    u = u + "***" + "+++" + "---";
}

System.out.println(u);
```

Comment: The question is far too vague... using just one iteration (for loop) and printing the above string would solve your problem.

Comment: Just do `String u = "***+++------+++***";`. Or explain better.

Comment: Should be three nested loops.

Comment: @RomanC - One loop to go over each symbol, one loop to count to 3, and one loop for...wnat? To go in reverse?

Comment: @TedHopp The loop to go over each symbol is not necessary but with it it will be four loops as OP requested.

Comment: @eldarerathis Thanks for the edit, but you don't understand. There was mistake not `for-loop` and not `foreach-loop` but `four loops` simple `do-while`.

Comment: @RomanC: I don't see any evidence that the OP intended to use the number 4 (or "four") in that location rather than the word "for", referring to the loop construct demonstrated in the code sample. Unless the OP comes back to clarify I don't really think it's an accurate assumption.

Comment: @eldarerathis To be more correct in terms the `for` is a `statement` in the Java language. If and if using a buzzword like _for_ loop is express the _for_ statement but not in plural value. In plural it has other meaning.

Comment: @RomanC - You are the only one who is reading "`for` loops" as "four loops". I think that's just wrong-headed. OP wants one or more `for` loop constructs. I still don't understand your comment _"Should be three nested loops."_

Comment: @TedHopp I don't care how do you think wrong-headed or without head. I has opened Java programming Language, 4th Ed By Ken Arnold, James Gosling, David Holmes ch.10.5. For.

Comment: @RomanC From the [Java Language Tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html): _"The for statement provides a compact way to iterate over a range of values. Programmers often refer to it as the "for loop" because of the way in which it repeatedly loops until a particular condition is satisfied."_ That page also uses the plural: "`for` loops". The [Wikipedia page _"For loop"_](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/For_loop) also uses the plural "for loops". I could cite many other sources. It's a common English usage which, apparently, was just unfamiliar to you.

Comment: @TedHopp Look at [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.14) I don't know what programmers often doing, many of them like you use such a buzzword referring terms in vulgar manner. But I prefer to use standard terms instead of using an undefined sense of expression.

Comment: @RomanC - I agree that the Java Language Specification does not use the term "`for` loops" (in the plural). However, it _does_ use the term "`for` loop" (in the singular) as a noun phrase. (See, for instance, the caption to Example 14.16-1.) In standard English, the plural of the noun phrase "`for` loop" is "`for` loops". There is no way in standard English that "`for` loop" means one thing and "`for` loops" has some other meaning than the plural (as you suggested in your third comment back). Furthermore, I certainly don't consider that to be vulgar, merely colloquial.

Comment: @RomanC - The real point I'm trying to make, though, is that even if there is an argument to be made (which I doubt) that "`for` loops" is somehow vulgar, or even incorrect, usage, it's clearly what OP had in mind. It was most certainly wrong to edit it to say "four loops", which makes no sense.

Comment: @TedHopp I did my point here. And I have my opinion. Suddenly, I cannot state it unless my point will be accepted by the community instead of making it impossible to express.

Answer (score 5):

Well, you could do this:

```
for (int i = 1; i < 2; ++i) {
    System.out.println("***+++------+++***");
}
```

But presumably that's not what you want. How about this:

```
String symbols = "*+-";
for (int s = 0; s < symbols.length(); ++s) {
    char c = s.charAt(s);
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
        System.out.print(c);
    }
}
for (int s = symbols.length() - 1; s >= 0; --s) {
    char c = s.charAt(s);
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
        System.out.print(c);
    }
}
System.out.println();
```

Or else:

```
String symbols = "*+-";
int len = symbols.length();
StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
for (int s = 0; s < len; ++s) {
    char c = s.charAt(s);
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
        output.append(c);
    }
}
System.out.print(output);
System.out.println(output.reverse());
```

Or even:

```
String symbols = "*+-";
int len = symbols.length();
StringBuilder prefix = new StringBuilder();
StringBuilder suffix = new StringBuilder();
for (int s = 0; s < len; ++s) {
    char c1 = s.charAt(s);
    char c2 = s.charAt(len - 1 - 1);
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
        prefix.append(c1);
        suffix.append(c2);
    }
}
System.out.print(prefix);
System.out.println(suffix);
```